# jQuery class on change if at least one input field is filled, then change value in another (hidden) field

Tags: jquery

Here http://jsfiddle.net/MFa6Q/ placed example

Have more than one input field.

On each change of input field (user typed or deleted in input field) want to check all other input fields of particular row. And if at least one of the input fields is filled (not empty), then change value in another (hidden) input field.

Here is my code

html

```
<table>

<tr id='row78'>

<td class="dropdown">
<select name="currency[]" id="currency78" class="row_changed78 row_changed_currency78">
<option value=""> </option>
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
</select>
</td>

<td><div style="width:80px; border:0px solid #F1F1F1;">
<input type='text' name='transaction_partner_registration_number[]' id='transaction_partner_registration_number78' class='row_changed78' value='' size='' style='width:80px;'>
</div></td>


<td>
<input type="text" name="is_row_changed[]" id="is_row_changed78" size="" value="" style='width:30px;'>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="is_row_changed_not_empty[]" id="is_row_changed_not_empty78" size="" value="" style='width:30px;'>
</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

jquery

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {


$(".row_changed78").on("change", function () {
document.getElementById('is_row_changed78').value = 1;
});



$(".row_changed78").on("change", function () {


$(".row_changed78").find('input[type=text], select').each(function(){

if($(this).val() != "" ) {
document.getElementById('is_row_changed_not_empty78').value = 1;
}

});


});



});//document ready
</script>
```

For necessary input fields I defined `class="row_changed78"`. And jQuery checks if value changed in input fields with `class="row_changed78"`. If value changed then need to check all other fields of the row. If at least one field is filled, then change value in `id="is_row_changed_not_empty78"`.

All work for `id="is_row_changed78"` (if value is changed). But does not work for `id="is_row_changed_not_empty78"`.

Comment: Just as a guess, you're planning to copy-paste your code for all your rows like `changed79` ?

Comment: @ Roko C Buljan I will use php `while ($counter < $counter_maximum){`

Comment: I mean inside the jQuery...

Comment: At the moment decided jquery to place just below html input (not in head as in the example). And jquery like this `$(".row_changed<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row_number , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");?>").on("change", function () {`

Comment: But for one another situation in head `<script>` also used php. like `<?php
while ( $counter_json < ($counter_maximum+1) ){
if ($counter_json > 0){
?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.find('input[type=text], select')` and it works. Because all inputs and the select already have the `row_changed78` class, so the `.find()` gets empty. Use just:

```
 $(".row_changed78").each(function () {
```

My suggestion:

```
$(".row_changed78").on("change", function () {
    var flag = '';
    $(".row_changed78").each(function () {
        if (this.value != "") {
            flag = 1;
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('is_row_changed_not_empty78').value = flag;
    document.getElementById('is_row_changed78').value = 1;
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vT9p7/)